# What is the difference between ! and % in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook

Both `!` and `%` allow you to run shell commands from a Jupyter notebook.

- `%` is provided [by the IPython kernel](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) and allows you to run "magic commands", many of which include well-known shell commands.
- `!`, provided by Jupyter, allows shell commands to be run within cells.

I haven't been able to find [much](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) comparing the two, and for simple shell commands like `cd`, etc. The main difference I see is that `%` is interactive and will actually change your location in the shell *while in the notebook*.

Are there other points or rules of contrast when thinking about which symbol to use for shell commands in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: `!` is not provided by Jupyter: it is also provided by the IPython kernel.

Answer (score 93):

`!` calls out to a shell (in a new process), while `%` affects the process associated with the notebook (or the notebook itself; many `%` commands have no shell counterpart).

`!cd foo`, by itself, has no lasting effect, since the process with the changed directory immediately terminates.

`%cd foo` changes the current directory of the notebook process, which is a lasting effect.

Comment: As a sidenote, `%ls` gives a colored output where as `!ls` doesn't

Comment: Returns from `!` are treated as string (even though its an error), where as returns from `%` are colored indicating if its a stdout or stderr

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh , who are we fooling, this is obviously the most important difference

Answer (score 4):

The exclamation mark (!) executes shell commands within a Jupyter Notebook cell when you type (!) followed by a shell command, Jupyter Notebook sends the command to the shell to run, on the other hand, the percent symbol (%) is used to execute special commands, called "magic commands", that are specific to Jupyter Notebook and not valid as shell commands for example:%matplotlib inline to enable inline plots.

However, % is also capable of sending shell commands like "ls", "cd" or "pip install" to the Juypter Notebook to execute. One difference I noticed as well is that In the latter case "pip install" will target the active virtual environment associated with the Jupyter Notebook kernel while if I do "!pip install" visual studio code will complain asking to use % in order for the packages to be installed to the right virtual environment.