# What is the difference between !{} and !$ in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am running this command in my jupyter notebook in two ways:

```
! {sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

and

```
! $sys.executable -m pip install numpy
```

both gives same output.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784499/difference-between-and-in-jupyter-notebooks) answer your question?

Comment: @LinuXMan no. the link revolves around the similar topic but it not what i am looking for.