# How to import an old commit of a Python module I wrote myself in a script?

Tags: python, bash, git, spyder

**I would like to import an old commit of a Python module (that I wrote myself) in a script.**

I've found a [solution here](https://towardsdatascience.com/workflow-for-reportable-reusable-and-reproducible-computational-research-45d036c8a908). It says to write the following at the top of the file.

```
%%bash  cd <project>_func # move inside the directory where you have the repository you need 

git checkout <git commit id> # restore the version of the code you will use
```

(`<project>_func` is the name of the directory containing the module I need to import.)

I've tried writing at the top of the script in which I'm importing my module, but it just returns a syntax error. I'm using Spyder, not running the script from a shell.

**What is the correct way to implement that?**

---

After **@Kavindu Ravishka** comment, I'm including all the steps to reproduce the error below:

1°) Directory structure :

```
    ├── ModDir
    │   └── mod.py 
    └── ScriptDir
        └── script.py
```

2°) Contents of mod.py :

`com_nb = 1` for the first commit

3°) Open shell in ModDir

4°) Type :

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'com_nb = 1'
```

Then

```
git log
```

which returns

```
commit 1234a # commit id was modified for clarity
Author : me <me@me.me>
Date : Today

    com_nb = 1
```

5°) Create script.py in ScriptDir, with the following contents :

```
%%bash  cd /absolute/path/to/ModDir
git checkout 1234a

from pathlib import Path
import sys
path_root = Path(__file__).parents[1]
sys.path.append(str(pathroot))

from ModDir.mod import com_nb
print(com_nb)
```

6°) Go back to step 2 and modify the contents of mod.py :
`com_nb = 2`

7°) Once again, open a shell in ModDir and type:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'com_nb = 2'
```

8°) Run script.py in Spyder. My hope would be that it prints 1, the value of `com_nb` in the first commit. Instead, it returns `SyntaxError : invalid decimal literal`, pointing to the "1" in `1234a` because, I assume, it doesn't interpret the first two lines in script.py as bash commands.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you be much more descriptive

Comment: Include details about your problem in the question as much as possible

Comment: @KavinduRavishka : I have edited my question to include a lot more details on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `%%` is not Python code and is not valid bash either. It appears to be IPython and/or Jupyter code: see [What is the difference between ! and % in Jupyter notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45784499/1256452)

Comment: @torek : thanks for the clarification! I had copied the code from my link in the main post not knowing anything about how to invoke shell commands in a script. @KavinduRavishka has provided the correct way to do it (using `os`), but I'm now having troubles with the behaviour of `git checkout` (which I'm not familiar with) - see my comment under @KavinduRavishka's answer.

Comment: You might be better off breaking up the problem differently: have a script (probably bash) that extracts the desired pieces, then runs the Python code that you want where the Python code never has to attempt to load other Python code *after* running Git. This will let you debug each part separately: i.e., first, you get some bash script working with some Git commands, *then* you get the Python code working. (In particular, using `os.system` is extremely crude and has no error handling unless you add some.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your Problem. And tried several changes

```
%%bash  cd /tmp
git checkout 1234a

%%bash  cd /tmp
#!git checkout 1234a

%%bash  cd /tmp
!git checkout 1234a

%%bash  cd /tmp
%%git checkout 1234a
```

All were failed with errors. If you trying to run shell commands via python use `os` library.

```
import os

os.system("bash cd /absolute/path/to/ModDir")
os.system("git checkout 1234a")
```

this would solve the problem

Comment: I add to change a bit the code you suggested to make it work: 

```import os

os.chdir("/absolute/path/to/ModDir/")
os.system("git checkout -f 1234a")
```

The problem is that this now rolls back mod.py to the first commit, which isn't what I want. I would like mod.py to remain at the latest version (`com_nb = 2`) but that script.py would import the older commit  (`com_nb = 1`), so that `print(com_nb)` in script.py returns 1, not 2.