# Why doesn't sqlalchemy_redshift work in my Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sqlalchemy

I have a feeling it's not happy with the python version? But not sure how to change it. I went into the Kernel option and there is a venv there, but it's also 3.10

[image]

Comment: Try to install with `%` like `%pip install your_package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install using `%` instead `!` like
`%pip install your_package`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787827/8353711) more details on difference between `%` and `!`

> `!` calls out to a shell (in a new process), while `%` affects the process
> associated with the notebook (or the notebook itself; many % commands
> have no shell counterpart).